# How can I populate a select tag using knockout js and jquery?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, knockout.js

I am simply trying to populate a couple of select tags that I render with jquery.

Incoming model from the server:

```
public class DepthChartsVm
{
    public List<DepthChartModel> ReturnDepthCharts {get;set;}
}

public class DepthChartModel
{
    public Team Team {get;set;}
    public int SportId {get;set;}
}

public class Team
{
    // various properties
    public List<AthleteInfo> AthleteInfo {get;set;}
    public List<positions> BasketBallPositonList {get;set;}
}

public class AthleteInfo
{
    // various properties
    List<DepthChart> DepthChartPositions {get;set;}
}

public class DepthChart
{
    // various properties
    prop ...etc
}

public class Positions
{
   // various properties
   prop ... etc.
}
```

Html:

```
                                <div class="col-sm-4">
            <label for="teamDropDown" class="text-center">Teams</label>
            <select id="teamDropDown" data-bind="options: depthVm.ReturnDepthCharts, value: selectedTeam,
                optionsText: function(item){return item.Team.FullName},
                optionsCaption: 'select'"></select>
            <p data-bind="if: selectedTeam">
                <strong>Sport: </strong> <span data-bind="text: selectedTeam().Team.Sport"></span><br />
                <strong>Season: </strong> <span data-bind="text: selectedTeam().Team.Season"></span>
            </p>
        </div>
        <!--Athletes-->
        <div class="col-sm-4">
            <div data-bind="if: selectedTeam">
                <h3 class="text-center">Athletes</h3>
                <div data-bind="foreach: selectedTeam().Team.AthleteInfo">
                    <p>
                        <strong>Name: </strong><span data-bind="text: FirstName()
                            + ' ' + LastName()"></span>
                    </p>
                    <div data-bind="foreach: DepthChartPositions()">
                        <p>
                            <input class="hidden" name="InputUpdateDepthChart.RosterId"
                                   data-bind="value: RosterId"/>
                            Position: <select name="InputUpdateDepthChart.PositionId"
                                    data-bind="options: $root.selectedTeam().Team.BasketBallPostionList, 
                                    optionsText: 'Position', value: PositionId, optionsValue: 'Id'"></select>
                            String: <select name="InputUpdateDepthChart.StringId"
                                    data-bind="options: DepthStrings, optionsText: 'String',
                                        value: StringId, optionsValue: 'Id'"></select>
                        </p>
                        <p>
                            <button data-bind="click: $root.addPosition">Add Position</button>
                        </p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    // script that serializes the model and passes it to knockout
    <script>
        // json encode incoming model

        var depthModelData = @Html.Raw(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Model))

        // update depth chart vM
        ko.applyBindings(new UpdateDepthChartVm(depthModelData),
            document.getElementById('updateDepthChartForm'));
    </script>
```

View Model:

```
                    var UpdateDepthChartVm = function (model) {
var self = this;
self.depthVm = ko.mapping.fromJS(model);

// selected team 
self.selectedTeam = ko.observable();

// add position
self.addPosition = function () {

    self.selectedTeam.Team.AthleteInfo.DepthChartPositions.push(new depthChartPosition());
};

function depthChartPosition(values) {
    values = values || {};
    var model = {
        RosterId: ko.observable(values.RosterId),
        PositionId: ko.observable(values.PositionId),
        StringId: ko.observable(values.StringId),
    };
    return model;
}
```

};

Basically I'm trying to duplicate the first paragraph on the fly when a user wishes to add another position. The jquery does work in terms of rendering a new paragraph with the select tags, but the select fields are empty, as it appears that there is no binding between them and my view model. Other than this my view model is working. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Knockout Mapping will only add observable wrappers around the properties in the first level of the supplied object. I'm assuming the object you're feeding into the `ko.mapping.fromJS` method is a JS representation of the `DepthChartsVm` C# model. Therefore, only the `ReturnDepthCharts` property will be observable. The simple answer is to supply mapping customizations such as:

```
var depthChartsVmMapping = {
    Team: {
        create: function(options) {
            return ko.mapping.fromJS(options.data, teamMapping);
        }
    }
}
var teamMapping = {
    AthleteInfo: {
        create: function(options) {
            return ko.mapping.fromJS(options.data, athleteInfoMapping);
        }
    }
}
var athleteInfoMapping = {
    DeptChartPositions: {
        create: function(options) {
            return ko.mapping.fromJS(options.data);
        }
    }
}

var self = this;
self.depthVm = ko.mapping.fromJS(model, depthChartsVmMapping);
```

Yes, I agree this makes the mapping module seem a bit burdensome but consider the possibility that your model contains too many levels. For instance, do you really need to load all teams, with all their athletes, and each athlete's depth chart positions? A more conventional REST-like implementation might be to asynchronously load the necessary resources as they're needed. Obviously, I don't have any idea how your app is presented but I intuit that in this case, you might have:

- An observableArray of teams; initially containing only summary information
- An observable to store the currently selected team
- An operation to get details for the team (which may include athletes with depth chart information

You can make your mapping work with customizations as exemplified above so don't worry if you're not following me. However, if you're up for some refactoring, I'd rally behind that cause!

Hope that helps!

```
var vm = {
    Teams: ko.observableArray(),
    CurrentTeam: ko.observable(),
}
```

Comment: For whatever reason, SO wouldn't let me commit the edits on my previous answer so I had to submit a new one. Sorry for the delay. I was hoping the edit submission error would be sorted out.

Comment: Okay, now I'm feeling especially dense.  So I understand the mapping concept initially, but I'm confused on how to actually apply it to the view model.  I mean since there are several properties that need mapping, do I have to call ko.mapping for each mapping? For example, in the above code you have self.depthVm = ko.mapping.fromJs(model, modelMappings);  Where is modelMappings defined at? Or do I have to call that statement over and over and replace the modelMapping with each individually defined mapping?

Comment: Sorry modelMappings was an error. Its corrected now. Again, ko mapping won't recursively explore your model to create observable properties at every level. Instead, only the properties that are direct children of the supplied model will be observable. Does that much make sense?

Comment: Ok, I get it now.  Thanks for your time, you provided me with some valuable insight on knockout, and you're absolutely right in terms of my model.  That really is the problem.  I have entirely to much data returning from the server to just one model.  I am going to refactor my code accordingly.  Thanks again!

Comment: Glad I could provide some value to you! When I first started using knockout to build more SPA-like apps, I was making heavy use of the ko.mapping module. These days, I almost never use it mostly due to the fact that I'm making heavy use of WebAPI to get data into my UI. Best of luck!

Answer (score 1):

The reason the subsequent select elements don't have any options is because they aren't bound. Remember that ko.applyBindings is what brings your HTML to life so to speak. Since these items are added after the fact, they're not being tracked by ko.

There is actually a better way to do this with knockout's observableArray. Its much cleaner, DRY, and testable. And you were so close!

```
var UpdateDepthChartVm = function (model) {
var self = this;
self.depthVm = ko.mapping.fromJS(model);

self.selectedTeam = ko.observable();

self.addPosition = function () {
    self.depthVm.DepthChartPositions.splice(0, 0, new depthChartPosition());
    // I used splice because I believe you were wanting the UI element to be added to the
    // top of the list. Otherwise you could just use `push(new depthChartPosition())`.
};

// this bit isn't required but it's my preference
function depthChartPosition(values) {
    values = values || {};
    var model = {
        RosterId: ko.observable(values.RosterId),
        PositionId: ko.observable(values.PositionId),
        StringId: ko.observable(values.StringId),
    }
    return model;
}

// you also might want to use the above constructor in your mapping. again, just my preference
function mappings() {
    return {
        DepthChartPositions: {
            create: function(options) {
                return new depthChartPosition(options.data);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Remember, knockout.js is an MVVM (Model View View-Model) framework. Let the view model data drive the UI while being ignorant of it while having the UI be as simple as possible.

**EDIT**

Taking a close look at your view model, I see that there are two `DepthChartPositions`: one a member of `self.depthVm` (which should be an observableArray thanks to ko.mapping), the other of `selectedTeam().Team.AthleteInfo`. The later is the object to which the UI elements are bound. I do see that your `addPosition` function is modifying the proper object, however I don't know how this object is being created. My guess is that this is not an `observableArray`. You can test it like so:

```
ko.isObservable(self.selectedTeam.Team.AthleteInfo.DepthChartPositions)
```

Comment: So I tried to make the suggested changes to the code, but it is still not working. At this point I suspect that it may have more to do with the way objects are nested in my view model, so I've updated the html above to reflect the entire view model.  Hope this sheds some light on what I am doing wrong here.  Again, everything is working up until the point of the self.addPosition function.

Comment: Can you verify that `self.selectedTeam.Team.AthleteInfo.DepthChartPositions` is an observableArray?

Comment: You're asking the wrong guy, lol! But seriously, I'm a bit in over my head right now.  I am assuming that it is observable since the entire model was brought in via ko.mapping, but I'm brand new to knockout so I am not really sure.

Comment: Please see my updated answer. If the object in question is actually being created by `ko.mapping`, it's not happening in the code you've posted so far. Did you leave that code out?

Comment: So I added the the initial model from the server above to provide some clarity on the nesting.  I also added the script to the html code above to show the initial ko binding.  So I believe you're right about the observable. I checked as you suggested and sure enough it came up undefined.  So the way that I appear to have it set up, is once an initial team is selected by the user, that object is passed to the selectedTeam observable via the value parameter on the options binding. So I imagine this is where the problem lies. Hopefully this clarifies things somewhat.

Comment: Yes, the problem is due to the complex nature of your model. Knockout mapping does not operate recursively. It will only create observable objects for the first level of the supplied model. You need to use a custom mapping. I'm trying to add an edit with some code but SO is giving me fits. I'll keep trying but if it's faster you can take a look at http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/plugins-mapping.html